# Design pattern opinions/suggestions for Blazor Server-side

Tags: blazor-server-side

The Blazor server-side template structure is a little confusing to me. 
/Data for Model and Controllers?

Does anyone have any **opinions** or suggestion for structuring/renaming folders for a Blazor server-side app?

New to .NET Core and design patterns so any advice greatly appreciated.
And please, only those that have built with Blazor server-side templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been wondering the same thing...
You could remove /Data and use /Models /Controllers for starters. 
Not sure about /Pages /Shared and how moving them would effect the app.
but could try.

`/Models
 /Controllers
 /Views
   /Pages
   /Shared`